# Breath of Life and hp based Death Effects

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, character-death

The spell [Breath of Life](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/breath-of-life) says quite explicitly:

> Creatures slain by death effects cannot be saved by breath of life.

But I have some issue regarding what "slain by death effects" means. Let's say a character is on the wrong end of a [Wail of the Banshee](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/w/wail-of-the-banshee). It doesn't kill instantly, but has a death descriptor and so is supposedly considered a death effect.

The character fails his save and is reduced to -5 hp. Is he considered "slain"? Would a Breath of Life work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If the the death affect failed to kill the character, breath of life can still be used to heal them because they were not 'slain'.

'Slain' is never defined anywhere, so the normal definition of 'killed' applies. The rules text backs this up:

> Unlike other spells that heal damage, **breath of life can bring
>   recently slain creatures back to life**.

Breath of Life only fails when the creature has died as a result of the death affect.

In the particular case, the wounded character could take more damage that would result in its death and have a Breath of Life spell bring them back to life.